# get data from a .txt file and write it on a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, streamwriter, microsoft-translator

I am trying to create a language translator I have the texts that translated the word that I need here is an example of what is inside my text file https://pastebin.com/LBv76w2f
and I have two text boxes in my program, I want to get data from the text box 
and write it in the second text box based on the text file that I have the words in it something like

`if (englishtextbox.Text == "yttrium")
{
                kurdishtxtbox.Text` = "لقي:  پزيشكي" + "\r\n" + "كوردي: هێماي كيميايي ييتريۆمە" + "\r\n" + "وردەكاري: هێماي كيميايي ييتريۆمە ";

}

but you know I don't like to type 100 000 else ifs. thanks for help ;)

Comment: Can you make your problem a little more clearer? For me it's hard to understand what's your problem.

Comment: @zgue i have a text file that have 100k words like this
 ||English : xyster||
||
لقي:  گشتي ||
||
كوردي: ئامێري ئيسقان كڕاندن (پزيشكەواني)||
||
وردەكاري: ئامێري ئيسقان كڕاندن (پزيشكەواني)||
||
and i have two text boxes in my program i want to get data from the txt file while the textboxs text equals to yttrium the other text boxs text = لقي:  گشتي 
كوردي: ئامێري ئيسقان كڕاندن (پزيشكەواني)
وردەكاري: ئامێري ئيسقان كڕاندن (پزيشكەواني)
i want to it to get the data from the first texbox and translate it based on the txt file that i have and write it in the second textbox

Answer (score 1):

Create a table  with 2 fields in DB

```
Column_1 column_2
```

Then use query

```
Select column_2 from table where column_1 = englishtextbox.Text
```